# React createPortal with useRef does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      {ref.current !== null &&
        createPortal(<span>Hello!</span>, ref.current as any)}
      <div ref={ref}></div>
    </>
  );
```

As far as I understand portals, a `span` should be appended to the `div`, however it is not.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes to refs do not trigger updates (re-renders). My guess is that your component is only rendered once, `ref.current` is set, but no re-render so you don't see the `span`.

For cases like this you probably better use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs):

```
const onRef = element => {
  if (element !== null) {
    createPortal(<span>Hello!</span>, element);
  }
};

return <div ref={onRef}></div>;
```

Comment: I tried this on a component but it doesn't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-brook-9w3f6c?file=/src/App.js Any idea why?

Comment: I improve solution and use useState hook as handler of callback ref. Here is working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-spence-96zchw