# How to create a portal to a child component?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a portal to insert a content in a child component but I can't make it work. I tried to use a callback ref as shown [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515159/9718056) but it doesn't work (the content of the portal is not displayed). Here is a simplified example of what I have:

```
const Parent = () => (
  <Child
    ref={(el) => {
      if (!el) return;

      const selector = el.querySelector(".title");
      createPortal("My title", selector);
    }}
  />
);

const Child = forwardRef((_, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}>
    <h2 className="title"></h2>
    <p>Test content</p>
  </div>
));
```

I also tried with `useRef()`, but to no avail.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef();

  const renderTitle = () => {
    const selector = childRef.current.querySelector(".title");
    return createPortal("My title", selector);
  }

  return (
    <Child ref={childRef}>
        {childRef.current && renderTitle()}
    </Child>
  );
}
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

I know the obvious solution is to pass the title as a prop but the `title` prop of my real `<Child />` component displays a simple text and I need a different display. I don't want to change `<Child />` as it can be used without `<Parent/>` and I use the latter to deal with other extra functionalities, which include building a custom title dynamically.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-brook-9w3f6c), if you want to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by storing the selector in a state using `useEffect`:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef();
  const [titleContainer, setTitleContainer] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const titleContainerSelector = childRef.current.querySelector(".title");
    setTitleContainer(titleContainerSelector);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Child ref={childRef}>
        {titleContainer && createPortal("My title", titleContainer)}
    </Child>
  );
}
```

It doesn't work when I try this on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-frog-htco6s) but it works on my real components. I'm not sure why. For the record, [here is the answer that gave me the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701646/9718056).

Answer (score 0):

Portals are not for these purposes. You can just pass Component to the child component. Or use the function to generate that name.

```
const Parent = () => (
  <Child
    titleComponent={<TitleComponent />}
  />
);

const Child = ((titleComponent) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h2 className="title">{titleComponent}</h2>
      <p>Test content</p>
    </div>
  )
});
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said, I don't want to edit my child component.